# Difference between == , = and eq

Tags: perl, operators, assignment-operator, equality-operator

I want to know the difference between these:

```
 my $a = 1;
```

and

```
 my $a == 1;
```

and

```
 my $a eq 1;
```

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=276023, 2nd hit with [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=perl+difference++%3D%3D++%3D++eq)

Comment: This is a perfectly fine and useful question, and a frequent gotcha in PERL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**==** is used when comparing numeric values.

**eq** is used in comparing string values.

**=** is the assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

`eq` is for testing string equality, `==` is the same thing but for numerical equality.

[For More Click Here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators)

Answer (score 1):

The last two statements do nothing, it's a good practice to use the directives:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $a == 1;
my $b eq 1;

print "$a $b\n";
```

you should see some warning such as:

```
Useless use of numeric eq (==) in void context at main.pl line 5.
Useless use of string eq in void context at main.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $a in numeric eq (==) at main.pl line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $b in string eq at main.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $a in concatenation (.) or string at main.pl line 8.
Use of uninitialized value $b in concatenation (.) or string at main.pl line 8.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never see the 2nd or 3rd examples in any perl program.  If you do, it would not be farfetched to assume the original programmer meant something else (like `my $a = 1;`).  Those would both give warning messages if you were were using the strict and warnings pragmas:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $a == 1;

# ==> Useless use of numeric eq (==) in void context at -e line 3.
# ==> Use of uninitialized value $a in numeric eq (==) at -e line 3.
```

You should also try to stay away from using `$a` or `$b` as variables in any perl program as these are considered special variables used when sorting.  You can often get away with it, but it's best not to mess around with them.