# Why does this string undef check return true?

Tags: string, perl, undef

```
my $line = "hello";
print ($line == undef);
```

The check should be false since $line is not undefined (I defined it in the first line). Why is this code snippet printing out '1'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between == , = and eq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396049/difference-between-and-eq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you said.

```
print ($line == undef);
```

You're printing out a boolean value because `($line == undef)` is a boolean statement.

The `==` is a *numeric* equals. Since `$line` is text, it has the value of `0`. So does `undef` numerically. Thus `($line == undef)` is true.

You should always put the following on the top of your program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

There are other pragmas people put, but these are the two most important. They will find 90% of your errors. Try this program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = "hello";
print ($line == undef)
```

You'll get:

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at ./test.pl line 6.
Argument "hello" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./test.pl line 6.
```

Of course I have an uninitialized value! I'm using `undef`. And, of course `hello` isn't a numeric value.

I'm not entirely sure what you want. Do you want to print out `hello` if it's not defined? Are you trying to see the value of that boolean statement?

What about that `\n` on the end that `print` doesn't put on the end of the line? Do you want that? Because `print` can be prone to the forgotten `\n` error, I prefer to use `say`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);   # Say is like print but includes the ending `\n`

my $line = "hello";
say (not defined $line);    # Will print null (false) because the line is defined
say ( defined $line);       # Will print "1" (true).
say ( $line ne undef);      # Will print '1' (true), but will give you a warning.
say $line if defined line;  # Will print out $line if $line is defined
```

Comment: Wow that was pretty detailed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Always put

```
use strict; use warnings;
```

or

```
use Modern::Perl;
```

you will see some errors :

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at /tmp/sssl.pl line 3.
Argument "hello" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at /tmp/sssl.pl line 3.
```

To test if a variable is defined, use :

```
print "variable defined" if defined $variable;
```

To test a string against another string, use :

```
if ($string eq $another_string) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah! thank you, I thought undef can be used as we use null in java